# How do I go about migrating books using MIgrate_D2D?

Tags: 7, migrations

I've had to rebuild my sites recently due to a hit on the [Drupalgeddon](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgeddon) bug I thought I closed. I've been trying to migrate everything in easily but it doesn't seem to want to for whatever reason.

Now, I use [migrate D2d](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) for the most part and except for groups, group posts, and books it works just fine, the issue is anything with [entity references](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) or hierarchies.

Comment: Well I found this little tidbit but I'm not exactly sure how to integrate it. 

https://www.drupal.org/node/1513766

There is a comment showing how to do this with migrate_d2d however I'm not sure if I'm even close to doing it right so I'm in the dark, any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I've added a comment (though I see it is the main text as well) about how to do this with the regular migration. It's not d2d, but it might help you: https://www.drupal.org/node/1513766

Comment: The above post does also contain a d2d specific example: https://www.drupal.org/node/1513766#comment-7321564

Comment: I realize this is almost a year after your original post and you most likely have resolved the issue already but in case you are still having issues with Drupageddon fallout, try this bash shell script which can help you recover your site. See https://github.com/uberhacker/drupalgetem. Let me know if this helps or if you are still having trouble migrating your site.